# In how many ways $3$ different rings can be worn in $4$ fingers with at most one in each finger?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $3$ different rings be worn on $4$ fingers with at most one on each finger?

Comment: Do you allow wearing less than three rings?

Comment: Yes. Any number of rings. @Flower

Comment: You're right, except there are 24 ways to fill it with all three rings.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you chose an answer that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first ring can go to one of the fours.
Your second ring can go to one of the threes.
Your third ring can go to one of the twos.

So, it is $4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$.

Comment: @Prabesh Joshi: You said "Any number of rings".

Comment: The actual question didn't mean that. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

$24+3\cdot 12+3\cdot 4+1=73$

Two ways to think about it: (m is max # of rings, n is # of fingers, k is # of used rings)

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$$