# In how many ways $5$ different rings can be worn on $4$ fingers?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, self-learning

> In how many ways $5$ different rings can be worn on $4$ fingers ?

Although these is similar question here [In how many ways $3$ different rings can be worn in $4$ fingers with at most one in each finger?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660452/in-how-many-ways-3-different-rings-can-be-worn-in-4-fingers-with-at-most-one)

But I want to answer it in different way which is like take $4$ fingers like $a,b,c,d$. Now $a$ can be filled in $5$ ways and so are others. So total ways are $5^4$ but answer is $4^5$. What is wrong in my reasoning? Which cases have I left out?

Comment: If you fill $a$ with $5$ then b, c, d don't have any rings.

Comment: The answer is $4^5$ because for each of the rings, you have four fingers to choose from.

Comment: @LazyLee why can't we have for each of 4 fingers , you have 5 rings to choose from

Comment: @kingW3 can you elaborate?

Comment: No, because for each of the $5$ rings, you have to select one of the fingers to put it on. Your case is for another problem: "How many ways can you put one ring onto each of four fingers, when each of the fingers can choose from 5 rings".

Comment: If a finger can't have more than one ring, how can you fit five rings on four fingers?

Comment: @TaylorTed A ring can't be on more than one finger so if you choose a finger $a$ for a ring $1$ then that same ring can't also be on another finger $b$ which is counted by $5^4$.

Comment: This question isn't stated precisely enough to have a single answer. For clarity, suppose there's just one finger - is there one way to wear 5 rings on one finger, or 5!=120 ways? (That is, does the order of the rings on one finger matter?) In the former case, the answer to your problem is $4^5$ - just choose a finger for each ring. But if order matters (my wife says it does), @ChristianBlatter has provided the correct solution. So the correct answer to your question is: "it depends."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $4^5$ because you have $4$ fingers for each of the ring. Or, in other words each ring have $4$ choices.
$$4\times4\times4\times4\times4=4^5$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since the order of rings on a finger matters.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the four fingers are given, e.g., the fingers of one hand without the thumb. An arrangement of five distinguishable rings on the four labeled fingers amounts to a linear arrangement of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and three indistinguishable zeros as separators. There are ${8!\over3!}=6720$ such arrangements. Note that a green ring and a blue ring on the index finger can be worn in $2$ ways.

Comment: If we let $0$ denote the lack of a ring and if given a linear arrangement, the first pair go on the first finger (in the specified order), etc then the sequence $10234500$ and $01234500$ should be considered equivalent but I don't see how your solution accounts for that?

Comment: @benguin : The zeros serve as separators.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes more sense :) I was considering an argument that first orders the rings ($5!$ ways) then uses stars-and-bars to place the rings onto the fingers ($C(5+4-1,4-1)$ ways) for a total of $5!C(8,3)$ which gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had only one ring. It then would be $4^1=4$ different arrangements/placements.
Now if we add one more ring, it will be $4\cdot4$ because we combine the four possible arrangements with yet another four arrangements which makes it $16$. This means you can have two rings on one finger. By the same token we would have $4^5=1024$ arrangements for five rings. And the person can have five rings on one finger or no ring at all on the finger.

If you had $5^4$ arrangements, it would mean $5^1=5$ different arrangements for one ring on four fingers. And that doesn’t make sense.

And finger $a$ can have **six possible arrangements**: either of five rings or no ring at all.

Hope my explanation was not confusing.

Comment: The answer $4^5$ is correct if we only care about which ring appears on which finger.  To see how to handle the problem in which the order of the rings on the fingers matters, see the answer by Christian Blatter.

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is B 6720
Since rings are distinct, hence they can be named as
R
1
,
R
2
,
R
3
,
R
4

a
n
d

R
5
.

## The ring
R
1
can be placed on any of the four fingers in 4 ways. The ring
R
2
can be placed on any of the four fingers in 5 ways since the finger in which
R
1
is placed now has 2 choices, one above the
R
1
and one below the ring
R
1
.
Similarly
R
3
,
R
4
and
R
5
can be arrange in 6, 7 and 8 ways respectively.
Hence, the required number of ways

## 4
×
5
×
6
×
7
×
8

6720

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 **different** rings .
But you want 4 rings .
Hence , there are 5C4 ways to select the rings .
Now , assuming atmost and atleast 1 ring is worn in one finger , total number of ways of selecting the fingers is 5C4 .
Now , once they are selected , notice that there are 4P4 i.e.(4!) Ways to arrange your selections within the fingers .
Hence total arrangements shall be 5C4 * 5C4 * 4P4 = 600

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You have to place all five rings on four fingers.  Moreover, the order in which the rings appear on the same finger matters.

Answer (score -1):

In your argument that finger a can be filled in $5$ ways is wrong. This means one ring can be worn in more than one finger which is not possible.

You must argue that the first ring can be worn in any of the fingers, so it has $4$ choices.
Similarly, each ring has $4$ choices.
Total ways$=4.4.4.4.4=4^5$.

Second Question: Select $3$ rings from given $4$ rings and arrange the $3$ rings.
Answer=$^4C_3\cdot 3!=24$.